# Is there any viewWillAppear equivalent function in NSObject class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, nsobject

I'm having an `NSObject` class having some methods, in my program execution i will call methods inside this `NSObject` class so whenever i call any of instance or class methods of this class i need some method like `UIViewControllers` `viewWillAppear` which calls whenever the view gets loads, How can i do this?

Any help is thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? When would such `viewWillAppear` methods get called? If it's an `NSObject` subclass then what does it mean to have `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: I think that the nearest things for an object are init methods, but still it's not a good way to think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean whenever you're calling a method inside a (subclass of) NSObject, you want to be notified of this? Maybe you can something fancy with key-value observing or something...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

But really, I'm wondering why you would want to do something like that.